# Convert polynomial ZZX or ZZ_pX to string

Tags: c++, ntl

NTL how to convert polynomial (ZZX or ZZ_pX) to string and how to assign string input to the polynomial like cin and cout operators?

I tried like the following:

`ZZX a = conv<ZZX>("[2 3 12]")`

But it gets error.

Comment: What error do you get? You should consider updating your post with that.

Comment: There is no conv<> method char array to ZZX

Answer (score 1):

As you can read from your error message: There is no function `conv` that converts a string to a polynomial or the other way around.

You can use `<<` on all NTL objects, e.g.

```
ZZX p;
p.SetLength(3);
p[0] = 0; p[1] = 1; p[2] = 2;
cout << p << endl;             // output: [0 1 2]
```

To read a string into a `ZZX` object you need to write your own function. This depends on how you actually get your input. If you read it from a file, you need to get the numbers from the string and set them via the `[]` operator. If you input it via the console, you can skip the string and directly build the `ZZX` object.

Finally you can use this to overload the `conv` function.